# VueJs GetParameter from URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url

How can i get parametere after / from URL and put it in variable (this.searchQuery)

```
loadUsers(){
    
    this.loading = true
    fetch(window.config.apiUrl + '/widgets/search-users?userServices=false')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.users = response.users;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
      .finally(() => (this.loading = false))
  }
},

mounted () {
this.loadUsers();
this.searchQuery = ''
```

}, '

Comment: url - http://localhost:8080/doctors/?s=smth

Comment: If I understand well you want to get "smth" from the url, is that it ?

Comment: @CharlesLavalard yea, but instead of smth, it can be any word that the client enters. I've meant that client enters any parameter before /?s= and this should be passed to a variable this.searchQuery

Comment: Oh! So you have an input in a form and you want that , whane the user sumbit to be redirected to localhost:8080/doctors?s=<whateverTheUserEnteredInInput>

Comment: @CharlesLavalard vice versa, localhost:8080/doctors?s=<whateverTheUserEnteredHere> and <...> should be passed to a form

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand your question

Comment: Check the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API), especially the "URLSearchParams" section